# Glitch in perspective/transform transition on MS Edge

Tags: css, css-transitions, microsoft-edge, css-transforms, perspective

I'm experiencing a strange issue on MS Edge. I want to animate a door (a div tag ) around the Y axis with the css rotateY() function, combined with perspective properties.
The issue is that interpolate angle from a positive value to a negative value (50deg => -100deg) produces a glitch near zero.

Here is the simplified code : https://codepen.io/stephanemill/pen/LYGowqo - Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

```
.wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    perspective: 500px;
   perspective-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  
  .flip {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: gold;  
    transition: transform 4s;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform: rotateY(50deg);
  }
  
  .flip:hover {
    transform: rotateY(-100deg);  
  }
```

It's not quite visible but the effect can be amplified depending on the context.

After a lot of testing, I know that:

- -this comes not from hover
- -the bug disappears when there is no perspective properties
- -the bug disappears for an interpolation from -3deg to -100deg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in Edge Legacy. The door looks like jerking once when transforming. I thinks that's due to different rendering engines used in different browsers.

To solve this issue, you can use CSS [transform perspective() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/perspective) instead of CSS [perspective property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective). The sample code is like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 200px;
  /*perspective: 500px;*/
  perspective-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.flip {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gold;
  transition: transform 4s;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(10deg);
}

.flip:hover {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-100deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flip">
  </div>
</div>
```

It works well in Edge Legacy. You could check the result:

[image]